# MongoDB GridFS image not loaded correctly

Tags: php, image, mongodb, src, gridfs

I am trying to save images to a MondoDB Collection using GridFS. To test this, I made the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php
// open connection
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('ImageDatabase');
$gridUploads = $db->getGridFS('images');

// save image
$fileName = 'C:\Users\Thomas\Pictures\commits.png';
$gridUploads->storeFile($fileName);

// load image
$doc = $gridUploads->findOne($fileName);

// dsplay image
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $doc->getBytes();

?>


</body>
</html>
```

This should upload the image to the collection and then get the same image from the collection and display it.

The collection content after this is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52a6fcdd1dc38f0c3c0016bf"),
    "filename" : "C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Pictures\\commits.png",
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2013-12-10T11:37:01.000Z"),
    "length" : 179952,
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "md5" : "768d618923442668ca2a60f02be59d52"
}
```

print_r($doc):

```
MongoGridFSFile Object
(
    [file] =&gt; Array
        (
            [_id] =&gt; MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] =&gt; 52a6fcdd1dc38f0c3c0016bf
                )

            [filename] =&gt; C:\Users\Thomas\Pictures\commits.png
            [uploadDate] =&gt; MongoDate Object
                (
                    [sec] =&gt; 1386675421
                    [usec] =&gt; 0
                )

            [length] =&gt; 179952
            [chunkSize] =&gt; 262144
            [md5] =&gt; 768d618923442668ca2a60f02be59d52
        )

    [gridfs:protected] =&gt; MongoGridFS Object
        (
            [w] =&gt; 1
            [wtimeout] =&gt; 10000
            [chunks] =&gt; MongoCollection Object
                (
                    [w] =&gt; 1
                    [wtimeout] =&gt; 10000
                )

            [filesName:protected] =&gt; images.files
            [chunksName:protected] =&gt; images.chunks
        )

    [flags] =&gt; 0
)
```

However the result's body content is:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/path-to/the-script.php">
```

Any ideads why?

Thanks!

Comment: The results content is an image tag?

Comment: Yep, I don't know what should actually happen, but I guess an img tag where the src attribute is the path to the php file is not it^^

Comment: I really have no idea how that is possible...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first code example (mixed HTML and PHP), you're echoing the image's bytes within the HTML itself. There is also the issue of calling `header()` after the response body has been sent (one of the first things discussed in the [`header()` PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)). I assume what you mean to do is have an `<img>` tag whose `src` attribute points to a separate PHP script that simply sets the `Content-type` header and returns the image bytes.

If you really do mean to output the image bytes within the page response, you should consider using data URIs:

- [Data URI scheme: Inclusion in HTML or CSS using PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP)
- [Stack Overflow: Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

However, pointing the `src` attribute to a PHP script is likely a better option (especially for large images). I can't explain how your original script generated:

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/path-to/the-script.php">
```

...but that is certainly what you should be aiming for here.

Regarding use of `MongoGridFSFile::getBytes()`, you should note that `getResource()` will be more efficient, especially for large images. Working with the resource allows you to reduce memory consumption by only loading two chunks (from GridFS) in memory at a time. A concise example of using `getResource()` to output file contents can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongogridfsfile.getresource.php#refsect1-mongogridfsfile.getresource-examples).